# Most DNS queries for TLDs do not pass through dnsmasq

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dnsmasq, openwrt

Most DNS queries for top-level domains from my LAN behind a router with dnsmasq 2.55 on OpenWRT 10.03.1 return negative results, e.g.:

```
$ dig com. ANY

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> com. ANY
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 36108
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;com.               IN  ANY

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 12 22:37:30 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 21
```

When using some external recursive server (e.g. `dig com. ANY @8.8.8.8`), the query result is successful.

I thought that the problem migh be that dnsmasq considers the query for `.com` as a query for unqualified name `com` (terminal `.` seems to be always stripped). But even when dnsmasq is configured to forward queries for com comains and undistinguished names:

```
server=/com/8.8.8.8,server=//8.8.8.8
```

results are the same.

However, some types of queries actually DO pass, like `NS` or `SOA`. Some other, which DO NOT pass and return `NOXDOMAIN`, besides `ANY`, are e.g. `DNSKEY` or `RRSIG`.

Corresponding lines from the dnsmasq log are:

```
Feb 12 21:41:13 myrouter daemon.info dnsmasq[11569]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53 for unqualified names
...
Feb 12 21:42:52 myrouter daemon.debug dnsmasq[11569]: query[DNSKEY] com from 192.168.1.5
Feb 12 21:42:52 myrouter daemon.debug dnsmasq[11569]: config com is NXDOMAIN
...
Feb 12 21:43:06 myrouter daemon.debug dnsmasq[11569]: query[NS] com from 192.168.1.5
Feb 12 21:43:06 myrouter daemon.debug dnsmasq[11569]: forwarded com to 8.8.8.8
```

I wonder if, and how, can be dnsmasq configured to return expected results fot those queries. (queries for "normal" hostnames work properly)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the [`domain-needed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/dnsmasq.8.html#contenttoc3) option enabled:

> ```
>   -D, --domain-needed
> ```
>
> Tells dnsmasq to never forward  A  or  AAAA  queries  for  plain names,
>   without dots or domain parts, to upstream nameservers. If the name is not
>   known from /etc/hosts or DHCP then a "not found" answer is returned.

Find where this is set (either `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` or the command line parameters) and remove it.

Comment: this dnsmasq really has `-D` option (though not defined in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, but in `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq`) and disabling it fixes the problem, however it is a good idea to use it to prevent some information leakage, so i wonder if the problem can be solved without disabling the `-D` param (to work for real TLDs, not for random names) .. interesting is that it is also blocking some other queries than `A` or `AAAA`..

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1CoCt.png

Comment: Michael, i insist that `com.` IS a DNS name :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the domain regex. This worked for me.

Just remove the regex over the domain:
`server=8.8.8.8#53`